# torchview does only show input tensor node

Tags: pytorch

torchview does only show the input dimensions of my network

[image]

```py
from torchview import draw_graph
net = torch.nn.Sequential(torch.nn.Conv2d((3, 256, 256)))
net = torch.nn.DataParallel(net, gpu_ids)
draw_graph(model=net, input_size=(4, 3, 256, 256))
```

I expected to see the full graph.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem is the `DataParallel` wrapper, that didn't allow torchview to see through the network.

By "unpacking" it using `net.module`, everything works as expected:

```py
from torchview import draw_graph
net = torch.nn.Sequential(torch.nn.Conv2d((3, 256, 256)))
net = torch.nn.DataParallel(net, gpu_ids)
draw_graph(model=net.module, input_size=(4, 3, 256, 256))  # note unpacking
```

[image]